# Hook menu to unset a link with conditions

Tags: drupal, menu, drupal-7, hook

I'm stuck with an issue on Drupal 7.

I have my main menu containing multiple links.
With the module menu_fields, I added a taxonomy to the menu links, and I want to alter this menu display based on the chosen one.

Problem is I do not know how to write my development.

I tested hook_menu(), hook_menu_alter(), hook_menu_alter_link() in my module but the dpm() I wrote in it never appears.

What I hope for is a hook with a param containing an array of the menu items.

Do you have an idea ?

> Progress: 
>   I manage to display something with hook_menu_alter() -I had to empty cache- but I can't find the main menu in the $items var.

Comment: You added taxonomy to menu or to menu item? And you want to alter whole menu or single menu items?

Comment: As I said in my post, I added this taxonomy to the menu links (items). What I need is to compare each menu item chosen taxonomy to a user field.

Comment: Yes, you did say that, but then you said that you want to alter "menu", not "menu item".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved using `mymodule_translated_menu_link_alter(&$item, $map)`.

You just have to do a `if ($item['menu_name'] == 'main-menu') {}` statement and add your code in it.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can think of is to collect menu tree with `menu_tree_all_data()` function:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_tree_all_data/7.x

and then to crawl tree structure (recursevly) and manually generate menu html.